# Nutch plugin that crawls for specific keywords

Tags: nutch

Is there any Nutch plugin that help me crawl only web pages that contains specific keywords that can be set by the Nutch user?

For example I only want to crawl web pages that contain both "job" & "apply" words or web pages that contain words like: "education", "experience", "benefits"?

If a plugin like this does not exist, can an existing one be adjusted?